# R apply function across rows, unexpected answer

Tags: r, apply

I don't understand what is going on here:

### Set up:

```
> df = data.frame(x1= rnorm(10), x2= rnorm(10))
> df[3,1] <- "the"
> df[6,2] <- "NA"
## I want to create values that will be challenging to coerce to numeric
> df$x1.fixed <- as.numeric(df$x1)
> df$x2.fixed <- as.numeric(df$x2)
## Here is the DF
> df
                   x1                 x2   x1.fixed   x2.fixed
1   0.955965351551298 -0.320454533088042  0.9559654 -0.3204545
2   -1.87960909714257   1.61618672247496 -1.8796091  1.6161867
3                 the -0.855930398468875         NA -0.8559304
4  -0.400879592905882 -0.698655375066432 -0.4008796 -0.6986554
5   0.901252404134257  -1.08020133150191  0.9012524 -1.0802013
6    0.97786920899034                 NA  0.9778692         NA
.
.
.
> table(is.na(df[,c(3,4)]))

FALSE  TRUE 
   18     2
```

I wanted to find the rows that ***got converted to NAs***, so I put in a complex apply that did not work as expected.  I then simplified and tried again...

### Question:

Simpler call:

```
> apply(df, 1, function(x) (any(is.na(df[x,3]), is.na(df[x,4]))))
```

which unexpectedly yielded:

```
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Instead, I'd expected:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

to highlight the rows (3 & 6) where an `NA` existed.  To verify that non-`apply`'ed functions would work, I tried:

```
> any(is.na(df[3,1]), is.na(df[3,2]))
[1] FALSE
> any(is.na(df[3,3]), is.na(df[3,4]))
[1] TRUE
```

as expected.  To further my confusion on what `apply` is doing, I tried:

```
> apply(df, 1, function(x) is.na(df[x,1]))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
[4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

Why is this traversing the entire DF, when I have clearly indicated both (a) that I want it in the row direction (I passed "1" into the second parameter), and (b) the value "x" is only placed in the row id, not the column id?

I understand there are other, and perhaps better, ways to do what I am trying to do (find the rows that have been changed to NA's in the new columns.  But please don't supply that in the answer.  Instead, please explain why `apply` did not work as I'd expected, and what I could do to fix it.

Comment: you shouldnt be passing `df` to the anonymous `function(x)`, it is already subsetting by row for you `apply(df, 1, function(x) (any(is.na(x[3:4]))))`

Comment: Hi Rawr, this is exactly what I was looking for!  If you put it into an answer, I'll thumb up & check mark as correct.

Answer (score 2):

To find the columns that have NA's you can do:

```
sapply(df, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
#      x1       x2 x1.fixed x2.fixed 
#   FALSE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
```

A `data.frame` is a list of vectors, so the above function inside `sapply` will evaluate `any(is.na(` for each element of that list, i.e. each column.

As per OP edit - to get the rows that have NA's, use `apply(df, 1, ...` instead:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I tried to be clear with expectations here.  I wanted information BY ROW, not BY COLUMN.  Sorry if that was not sufficiently clear.  To my knowledge, `apply` is the ONLY vectorization that lets me do work by row.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson haha, no it wasn't "sufficiently clear" when you explicitly said "by column" in OP, but ok, just replace `sapply` with `apply(df, 1, ...`

Answer (score 1):

`apply` is working *exactly* as it is supposed to. It is your expectations that are wrong.

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) is.na(df[x,1]))
```

The first thing that `apply` does (per the documentation) is coerce your *data frame* to a *matrix*. In the process, all numeric columns are coerced to character.

Next, each individual *row* of `df` is passed as the argument `x` to your function. In what sense is it meaningful to index `df` by the *character values in the first row in `df`*? So you just get a bunch of `NA`s. You can test this via:

```
> df[as.character(df[1,]),]
       x1   x2 x1.fixed x2.fixed
NA   <NA> <NA>       NA       NA
NA.1 <NA> <NA>       NA       NA
NA.2 <NA> <NA>       NA       NA
NA.3 <NA> <NA>       NA       NA
```

You say you want to know which *columns* introduced `NA`s, and yet you are `apply`ing over rows. If you *really* wanted to use `apply` (I recommend @eddi's method) you could do:

```
apply(df,2,function(x) any(is.na(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
rowSums(is.na(df))>0
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

to find the rows containing `NA`s.

I'm not sure, but I think this is a vectorized operation which might be faster than using `apply` in case you are working with large data.